# Referencing a subform as variable in a module

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I've been using a module to take the name of a form and a control as variables to change a property of a control on a form. For example:

```vb
Sub mySub(formName As String, controlName As String)

    Forms(formName).Controls(controlName).ForeColor = Colour.RedDark

End Sub
```

I'd like to do this for a property on a control on a subform as well, but can't quite figure out the syntax to also refer to the subform as a variable too.

I thought it might be something like:

`Forms(mainFormName).Form(subFormName).Controls(controlName).ForeColor = Colour.RedDark`

...but this isn't working (**Object doesn't support this property or method**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Access 2010 does not recognize a control property named *ForeColour*; but *ForeColor* is valid.  (I don't know whether there is a locale issue involved here but my locale is US English.)

Other than that, I think you're trying to access *ForeColor* through the `.Form(subFormName)` property.  Instead of that, reference the subform **control**, and from there the target control in its contained subform.

In this working example, *Form12* contains a subform control named *Child0*.  The subform control contains a form named *fsub2* which in turn contains a text box named *txtMemo_field*.  But note the name of the subform (the form name not the control which contains it) does not appear in this statement:

```vb
Forms("Form12").Controls("Child0").Controls("txtMemo_field").ForeColor = vbBlue
```

Comment: Good eyes on "ForeColour/ForeColor". Intellisense doesn't trigger at this level and I'm from the UK, hence this mistake.

Comment: It took me a while to discover that.  The turning point was `? Forms!Form12!Child0!txtMemo_field.ForeColour` gave me the same "not supported" error you reported.  That's when I finally noticed `ForeColour` vs. `ForeColor`  I mention this now because I think `Forms!FormName!SubformControl!TextBox.Property` could be a useful cross-check for your `Forms()`, `Controls()`, property approach.  It was for me.  :-)